# Delete cookies from specific domain

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer, cookies

I've been asked if it's possible to delete cookies in IE from specific domains via GPO?  I've googled around and I'm sure this is possible but haven't been able to find anything about deleting cookies from specific domains.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks
msindle

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a way to delete cookies with Group Policy.

Comment: The only group policy I can see that you can enforce is to empty the temporary internet file when the browser close, but that will clear all cookies

Comment: Ok that's what I've been finding as well, but I didn't know if someone knew some special magic on how to do this.  Thanks everyone!